# Sign Email with Certificate using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, email, certificate

I am trying to send email with "From Certificate". I am using Framework 4.0, and in C# X509Certificates class.

```
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(mSMTPServer, mSMTPPort);
sc.EnableSsl = true;
sc.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(certificatePath, certPassword)); 
sc.Send(mail);
```

Problem I am facing is certificate is not attached or signed with email "from" part. Can any one help me please, how I signed from part of email using C#.NET and Framework 4.0?

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATED:** Look at this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41727/An-S-MIME-Library-for-sending-and-Signed-Encrypted

For only sign, pass the parameter to encrypt as null.

Comment: still valid with .Net 6.0, if you generate new projects and copy the files

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend taking a look at [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) which you can use to digitally sign your email messages.

Then once you have a signed email, you can send it using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)'s SmtpClient class which is very similar to System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ClientCertificates are not used for signing the message, they are ONLY used for authenticating with the server via SSL.